# Помощь в формирование базы данных

Tags: java, sql, spring

Привет.
Делаю проект онлайн банка для портфолио на Spring.
Пока дело дошло до формирование базы. Нужна небольшая оценка опытных людей. Функционал будет самый минимальный. Перевод со счета на счет по номеру карты или по номеру счета. Будет две роли: админ и простой пользователь. Конструктивная критика приветствуется. Восстановление пароля будет по номеру карты путем отправки смс пользователю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне скоро предстоит самостоятельно изучать/пробовать базы данных, в какой программе вы такие схемы составляете? спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Я сделал в DbSchema. Но можно сделать и онлайн https://dbdesigner.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Связь из `user` к `account` надо делать 1 ко многим
2. Должна быть связка `account` к `transactions` - операции по счету могут
   проходить и без карты, а вообще в реале они идут все равно через
   счет/`account`
3. Не хватает мультивалютности
4. Поле `user_password` вызывает прилив крови к глазам - обзовите это
   `user_password_hash` - поскольку хранится не пароль, а хэш пароля

Comment: Наверное я перегнул с переводом по номеру счета. Думаю пока достаточно и номера карты. Вы не поверите, но в коде у меня и есть связь @OneToMany. Только не пойму как реализовать генерацию Внешнего ключа в дочерней таблице. Например мне нужно добавить account_id в таблице account из таблицы user. Может что-то вроде аннотации @GeneratedValue?